Building a Dark Pool for a Client: Any Open-Source Matching Engines in Java? Or Should I Build One from Scratch? Difficulty Level Insights?
I recently took on a new gig where I'm advising a medium-sized financial institution on building a dark pool (a private financial exchange). While I have experience in related areas, this is my first time dealing specifically with dark pools, so I’d love to hear from colleagues who are more experienced in this space.
One of my main concerns is the matching engine. I’ve seen a lot of crypto exchanges emerging lately, and I’m curious about what solutions they use. Are these engines typically built in-house, adapted from open-source projects, or based on commercial off-the-shelf products? If there are open-source matching engines in Java that could fit the requirements, I’d love to know more about them. If not, what are the challenges of building one from scratch? Any particular pitfalls to watch out for?
I’m also open to general advice on best practices or architectural considerations when building a dark pool. Any pointers, recommendations, or resources would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

There are a couple of open source exchanges out there (eg. peatio) but they look really terribly built. Matching engines are not complex algorithms, the challenge comes with scale and performance, so it entirely depends on the scope and performance of what you're looking to build.
